# problem with lock and installation

Tags: dpkg

I am getting to use Ubuntu recently.

While installing Firefox flash plugin, it took too long that I could not install another package i.e. /var/lib/dpkg/lock permission denied

I tried to interrupt the installation by remove lock file with rm -f and installed the other package

Situation turned even worse when I had to run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' again and still it took too long so I decided to quite by Ctrl-C

Now I cannot even install any other package. The error is:
"dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0011' near line 0:
 newline in field name `#padding'"

Why is it so troublesome with just a simple installation task?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this command in terminal:

```
 sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0011
```

After it tupe:

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

It might solve your problem.